# scala - how to infer the return type

Tags: scala, types, return, type-inference

Can you please explain to me how you infer the return type? see below. thank you.

```
   val examples = sc.textFile(params.input).map { line =>
          Vectors.dense(line.split(' ').map(_.toDouble))
        }
```

[EDIT]
I mean how do you deduce the result type. thank you.

Comment: return type is depends on the last statement of your code block

Comment: Rather than trying to deduce result types, use type ascription: `val x :Int = ...` Ascribe the type, `Int`, that you want, and think you should get. If the compiler tells you that's not the correct type then you can A) change the ascription to match the actual result type, or B) change the code to get the result type you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type inference works form back to forward.

```
sc.textFile(file).map { line => Vectors.dense(line.split(' ').map(_.toDouble)) }
```

Last method called in your main expression is `RDD.map(lambda)`, that returns an `RDD[whatever the lambda returns]`.

```
Vectors.dense(line.split(' ').map(_.toDouble))
```

Then, the last method called in lambda main expression is `Vectors.dense(doubles)`, that returns a `Vector`.

```
line.split(' ').map(_.toDouble)
```

Finally this line doesn't matter, because Vector has no type parameters, so nothing to infer.

So, if put all togheter, the return type is RDD[Vector].

The type of an expression is the type of its last piece of code evaluated. If it is a method with type parameters, in this case `RDD.map[B]`, that type parameter B is inferred from the expression used to bind that parameter.

Why back to forward? Here you are an example.

```
def method[T](value:T) = {    
  val a = value    
  val b = a    
  val c = b    
  c 
}

method("Foo")
```

`method("Foo")` returns a String, because, from back to forward =>
type of c, that is of type b, that is of type a, which is of type value, that is of type T, and finally T is of type String.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to DenseVector instead in order to infer proper return type

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{DenseVector, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val examples: RDD[DenseVector] = sc.textFile(file).map { line =>
        Vectors.dense(line.split(' ').map(_.toDouble)).toDense
}
```